# <xsl:decimal-format group-separator="{$myseparator}"/> in XSL

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

is it possible to set decimal-format in any way by using a variable or
similar?

Example:

The error I get :
"The element 'xsl:decimal-format' has an attribute 'grouping-separator'
with an illegal value of '$grouping_separator"

Setting the decimal-format via a xsl:attribute is not possible also.

Any hints appreciated.

Cheers,
Ranjith

Comment: Conceptually, if you are declaring an specific decimal format, its properties shouldn't be dynamically resolved. You can apply any decimal format later with `format-number()` function.

Answer (score 2):

The spec for [XSLT 1.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#format-number) and **[XSLT 2.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/2007/REC-xslt20-20070123/#dt-decimal-format)** both state that the value for the `grouping-separator` attribute must be a single character. It appears that AVT is not allowed.

On the other side, one can have multiple *named* decimal formats, so this can be used to provide variability in formatting numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You can't specify any of properties of a decimal format as attribute value templates (i.e. "{...}").

Assuming a small number of possible separators, what you could do is define multiple decimal-formats with different names for each different separator you would like to use. And then pass in a different name to the format-number function to select the format with the appropriate separator.