# Decimal format children

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm getting the following error for my XSL file:

```
cvc-complex-type.2.1: Element 'xsl:decimal-format' must have no character or element information item [children], because the type's content type is empty.
```

This is because I have the following code:

```
<xsl:decimal-format name="symbols" NaN="0">
    <xsl:attribute name="decimal-separator"><xsl:value-of select="$DecimalSeparator" /></xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="grouping-separator"><xsl:value-of select="$GroupingSeparator" /></xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="infinity"><xsl:value-of select="$Infinity" /></xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="minus-sign"><xsl:value-of select="$MinusSign" /></xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="NaN"><xsl:value-of select="$NaN" /></xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="percent"><xsl:value-of select="$Percent" /></xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="per-mille"><xsl:value-of select="$PerMill" /></xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="zero-digit"><xsl:value-of select="$ZeroDigit" /></xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="digit"><xsl:value-of select="$Digit" /></xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="pattern-separator"><xsl:value-of select="$PatternSeparator" /></xsl:attribute>
</xsl:decimal-format>
```

There are child attributes in the xsl:decimal-format tag which are not allowed. My question is how can I rewrite this so that I no longer get this warning?

Each of the attributes is set in the Java from the DecimalFormatSymbols using the Locale which is probably why it was written this way.

Is this the correct solution?

```
<xsl:decimal-format name="symbols" NaN="0" 
    decimal-separator="{$DecimalSeparator}"
    infinity="{$Infinity}"
>
```

etc.

Comment: What you want is not possible, you can't dynamically pass arguments to `xsl:decimal-format`. It's a good question. I searched for it on StackOverflow and it has already been answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4805164/xsldecimal-format-group-separator-myseparator-in-xsl

Comment: So the only way of solving this would be by having a decimal format for every possible locale, set a variable for which locale to use and pass that into any format-number call?

Comment: Yeah, I suppose that's the case. If you really want to define your formats externally, that's not very nice. I think you could generate an xsl file with only the `xsl:decimal-format` declaration in from a small program, and then `xsl:include` that file into your main stylesheet.

Comment: That's exactly what I've just started doing. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that **$DecimalSeparator** and **$GroupingSeparator**, etc, are parameters that you intended to pass into your XSLT stylesheet? There is another approach you can take, although it does involve doing some pre-processing, in the form on another transformation.

XSLT documents also happen to be well-formed XML documents. This means you can apply an XSLT transformation on an XSLT document. So what you could do is create a new XSLT document that can be applied to your current XSLT that simply copies it, but also adds the attributes to the **xsl:decimal-format**.

The process would be as follows:

1. Load your current XSLT
2. Load the 'localising' XSLT
3. Apply the 'localising' XSLT to your current XSLT to create a new 'localised' XSLT (in memory)
4. Apply this 'localised' XSLT to your current XML

For example, consider you had the current XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:decimal-format name="local" decimal-separator="." grouping-separator=","/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number(26825.8, '#.###,00', 'local')"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The 'localising' XSLT would then look like this

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:param name="DecimalSeparator" select="','" />
    <xsl:param name="GroupingSeparator" select="'.'" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="xsl:decimal-format">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@name" />
            <xsl:attribute name="decimal-separator"><xsl:value-of select="$DecimalSeparator" /></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="grouping-separator"><xsl:value-of select="$GroupingSeparator" /></xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you applied the 'localising' XSLT to the original XSLT (passing in the parameters as required), the output would look as follows:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:decimal-format name="local" decimal-separator="," grouping-separator="."/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number(26825.8, '#.###,00', 'local')"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You could then apply this new XSLT to your XML to hopefully give you the result you need.